# Find points inside a volume defined by a set of points in 3D space

Tags: 3d, point-cloud

**Summary:** Find points enclosed within other set of points in 3D space.

**Details:**

I have two set of points, A and B in same 3D space. About 8000 such A, B combos so lots of variety.

Both the points are already placed in 3D space following some predefined rules (distance of b should be atleast 2 away from a) and configs. They are static.

'B' is scattered in and around same space as A. It's basically water around object A.

If we can draw a surface around 'A' , it forms sort of irregular, rough polygons of various shapes and widths but within some max height in all cases.

There can be some space within A due to it's shape in which B can be present, not always though.

**Question:** How to find out which points from B are enclosed in A.

*'A' may not form a continuous enclosed shape, reason:*

Imagine it like, a crushed plastic water bottle (A) is in water tank (B), sliced by two parallel planes of X width. I need to figure which water(B) is within the bottle boundaries (A). If the bottle is sliced by two planes at any location, it gives three combos : a) the top slice, in which the cap is within the slice b) The mid, slice is cutting the bottle in center c) the bottom, in which the bottom is within the slice.

Case b will have two open sides, case a,c will have 1 open sides. In these cases the plane boundary should be used to get the enclosing location, this is why the width of these polygons (A) can be any but the height is maximum height of the slice.

I am using scipy, python so if there is any package which can help

Can't use convex hull as those straight lines can alter boundaries of irregular polygons.

**eg of A,** case b:

https://paste.debian.net/1221641/, this is a big ring like structure with lots of gap in between for b

https://paste.debian.net/1221666/ - this has really small gap which ma, may not hold a point.

case a,c:

https://paste.debian.net/1221667/ , small one, but you can get the idea

Thank You

Comment: I suspect this is a really hard problem. in part because it's so loosely specified. No way we can read your data. If you [edit] the question to show us some small example pictures we might be able to help - but I doubt it.

Comment: https://chart-studio.plotly.com/create/#/   You can use this to view. It's 3D shape so picture will not be accurate.

Comment: Is $A$ *just* a set of points? You start talking about it being made of irregular polygons. It takes more than a finite set of points to determine polygons. You need to be specific about how you are representing $A$. What determines its boundary. You say you don't want the convex hull, but then how do you define what is inside and what is outside? Is $A$ instead a *triangulation* of the surface? I.e., a set of abutting triangles that enclose the interior. If so you need to specify which trios of points form these surface triangles (and their orientation).

Comment: Once you've figured out how to actually represent your surface, the usual trick for finding out if a point is inside or outside is to draw a ray from the point out to infinity. The direction doesn't matter so usually just use one of the cardinal directions. Then you count how many times this ray crosses the surface. If it does so an odd number of times, the point is inside. If it does so an even number of times, the point is outside. Be careful about intersecting the polygon boundaries - they require special handling.

Comment: @PaulSinclair 'If we draw a surface'  then it's like a big irregular shape. By this i mean , I can't determine any volume/area formula. To define what is inside and what is outside is the question. Try visualizing the data here  chart-studio.plotly.com/create/#  . It will help to see how they look like

Comment: I have intention of dedicating the time to learn and use some new tool, and import all your data into it, to then have to make guesses about what you might actually be after. This is your problem, and your representation. If you don't know how your own representation of the region you are concerned with works, do not expect us to figure it out for you.

Comment: @PaulSinclair the shapes looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/f3HpE8x   Two examples, different views.

First was suppose to be ideal example with lots of space in between.

I realized something, there is a break in south side. That breaks the boundary.

Didn't realize such examples can exist. :(


It's not possible to define a boundary there.

Let's say we can define an imaginary boundary there, based on some angle rules ( i don't know yet).


This ring is the maximum width any shape can have.

Comment: Your problem is ill-defined, and that is an issue you need to work out. You want to find the $B$ that are "enclosed in $A$". But $A$ is just a set of points, and you have no concept of what "enclosed in $A$" might mean. You refer to $A$ as the "bottle boundary", but it is just a set of points. **It defines no boundary**. Until you indicate how to define a boundary from it, there is nothing that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *volumes*, one can do *cluster* analysis.  You do not actually obtain any approximation of the interface surface at all, only which cluster each point belongs to.  A cluster is a spatially connected set of points belonging to the same original set.  A pair of clusters is *connected*, if they belong to different original sets, but have a spatially connected pair of points.

The downside is that cluster analysis cannot really differentiate between *"separated by empty space"* and *"separated by another cluster"*.  That is, it cannot directly tell you if a cluster is completely enclosed by another cluster, or whether there is a hole in the outer cluster.  That kind of examination is done separately.

However, it will tell you connected clusters – subsets of points from the original sets with the interface surface between them – and whether the original sets of points are continuous or spatially separated into separate subsets.

Unfortunately, this requires *both point sets*; either as separate point lists (files), or with a fourth component signifying the set.  OP has only listed points from one set, and it is not clear whether *both* point sets are even available; and this analysis absolutely requires both sets to be feasible.

Comment: some example shapes: https://imgur.com/a/f3HpE8x    Yes, that cluster analysis will have some trouble in case of first example, in Bottom there is some gap.

Comment: @GSingh: Couldn't you replace your current single-set point example data with at least one *complete example*, with all known points from both sets (including which set each point belongs to)?  An image is really useless here, as is just showing one of the point sets.  This is frustrating.